# How to alert an input value

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am making a form that alerts a users input, this is what I have tried

```
    Name :<input type="text" id="name">
```

this is my JavaScript

```
    function nameIt() {
      var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        alert("name");
        }
```

Comment: alert(name) docent work

Comment: are you calling function nameIt somewhere in your code?

Comment: Where do you call `nameIt()`?

Comment: If `alert(name)` doesn't work, you are either not calling the function or calling it at the wrong moment (e.g. before the user provided any input).

Answer (score 3):

```
alert(name);
```

Quotations are for strings, name is a variable. Try now :)

Edit: Improved so you understand it better:

```
function nameIt() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    alert(name);
}
```

To run it you need to make a form similar to this one:

```
<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="submit" value="Test" onClick="return nameIt()">
```

Comment: Nope it ain't still working

Comment: @Favouronu - Have you called your function...?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you are alerting the string name and not the variable name. Better fix that

Comment: What's the point of providing a jQuery answer to a non-jQuery question?